# Distances in TOC entry of section with mark

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, lengths, documentclass-writing

I try to customize TOC entry of section via redefining `\l@section` and defining `\@section` macros.

My purpose was to add different mark (`\sectiontitlemark`) before section counter in main text as well as in TOC. I achieved the goal. **But problem arised with "space" between section counter and it body in TOC.**

This "space" is just a shift of text from the left border of the page, regardless of the presence of the section counter (and `\sectiontitlemark`) and it need to be calculated depending on total width of `\sectiontitlemark` + `\thesection` + dot. But the total width depend on width of `\sectiontitlemark`. In MWE it controlled by `\setlength\@tempdima{2.7em}`

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter


\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0.1em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{2.7em} % Space between number and section title need to be calculated
    \begingroup
    \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
    \leavevmode
    \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
    \hskip -\leftskip
    #1\leaders\hbox to .5em{\hss.\hss}\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss  #2}\par
    \penalty\@highpenalty%
    \endgroup
    \fi}

\renewcommand\section{\global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@section\empty}
\def\@section[#1]#2{\refstepcounter{section}%
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\sectiontitlemark~\thesection.}#1}%
                    \sectionmark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \@makesectionhead{#2}%
                    \@afterheading
                    }
\def\@makesectionhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \normalfont\large\bfseries \sectiontitlemark~\thesection.\hspace{1ex}#1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}
\def\@ssection#1{\refstepcounter{section}%
                 \if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makessectionhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makessectionhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                   \sectionmark{#1}%
                 \fi}
\def\@makessectionhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalfont\large\bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\def\sectiontitlemark{\S}
\section{section One may be very very very and very very long and wrap to next line}
\lipsum[1]
\def\sectiontitlemark{$\to$}
\section{section Two may be also very very very and very very long and wrap to next line}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think using `tocloft` might be easier here

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I never used `tocloft`. May be you can solve with it?

Answer (score 1):

I had found solution!
The main idea is to save length of counter with mark `\@sechead@len` to `toc`-file by `\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\sechead@len}{\the\@sechead@len}}` in `\@section` macro and use it with `\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{2}{3em}{\sechead@len}}`.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\sectiontitlemark{}
\newlength{\sechead@len}
\newlength{\@sechead@len}

\newif{\ifappendix}

\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{2}{3em}{\sechead@len}}


\renewcommand\section{\global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@section\empty}
\def\@section[#1]#2{\refstepcounter{section}%
                    \settowidth{\@sechead@len}{\sectiontitlemark~\thesection.\space}
                    \addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\sechead@len}{\the\@sechead@len}}
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\sectiontitlemark~\thesection.}#1}%
                    \sectionmark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \@makesectionhead{#2}%
                    \@afterheading
                    }
\def\@makesectionhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \normalfont\large\bfseries \sectiontitlemark~\thesection.\hspace{1ex}#1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}
\def\@ssection#1{\refstepcounter{section}%
                 \if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makessectionhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makessectionhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                   \sectionmark{#1}%
                 \fi}
\def\@makessectionhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalfont\large\bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\def\sectiontitlemark{\S}
\section{section One may be very very very and very very long and wrap to next line}
\lipsum[1]


\def\sectiontitlemark{$\to$}
\section{section Two may be also very very very and very very long and wrap to next line}
\lipsum[1]

\def\sectiontitlemark{ ------------1 }
\section{section Two may be also very very very and very very long and wrap to next line}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

It's interesting that I found the solution after couple of days of searching right after I described the problem here.

May be someone will find the more laconic solution.

[image]